How to implement an attribute accessible by everything within a scope
I want to know if it is possible in Kotlin to create a "Context" from which objects can get data from. Something like the following:
MyScope(myGlobalObject) {
    val objectA = MyClassA()
    objectA.doSomething()
}

ClassA() {
   fun doSomething() {
       val resultA = ...
       myGlobalObject.add(resultA)
       val objectB = ClassB()
       objectB.doSomethingElse()
   }
}

ClassB() {
   fun doSomethingElse() {
      val resultB = ...
      myGlobalObject.add(resultB)
   }
}

I wouldn't want MyScope to be a singleton because this is multi-threaded environment (server request) where I wouldn't want other threads messing up with context within local instances of MyScope
Code above is in the spirit of avoiding passing around myGlobalObject several levels down as follows:
val objectA = MyClassA(myGlobalObject)
objectA.doSomething()

ClassA constructor(val myGlobalObject) {
   fun doSomething() {
       val resultA = ...
       myGlobalObject.add(resultA)
       val objectB = ClassB(myGlobalObject)
       objectB.doSomethingElse()
   }
}

ClassB constructor(val myGlobalObject) {
   fun doSomethingElse() {
      val resultB = ...
      myGlobalObject.add(resultB)
   }
}

In other words, similar to other frameworks like React with ReactContexts. Been searching the internet and seems possible, JetPack compose has the feel of it but not sure if it possible to pass down data like above, or if there is a way to "reach" into a scope from any part of the code... I know it might return null or non-initialized but that is something I would be perfectly fine with

I believe you are looking for the experimental feature of Context Receivers. You can enable this by passing the -Xcontext-receivers compiler option.
Suppose you want your functions to access such an object:
// as per your requirements, not a singleton
class SomeGlobalObject {
    fun foo() {
        println("foo")
    }
    fun bar() {
        println("bar")
    }
}

You can prefix your function declaration with context(SomeGlobalObject):
context(SomeGlobalObject)
fun thisNeedsAGlobalObject() {
    // here you can use members of SomeGlobalObject without qualification
    foo()
    bar()

    // if there is ambiguity, you can qualify it with 'this@SomeGlobalObject'
    this@SomeGlobalObject.foo()
}

Functions that need a SomeGlobalObject can call other functions that need a SomeGlobalObject:
context(SomeGlobalObject)
fun somethingElseThatNeedsAGlobalObject() {
    thisNeedsAGlobalObject()
}

You can use with to start a scope where SomeGlobalObject exists:
fun main() {
    with(SomeGlobalObject()) {
        thisNeedsAGlobalObject()
    }
}

Adapting this to your ClassA and ClassB example, it would look like this:
fun main() {
    val globalObject = SomeGlobalObject()
    with(globalObject) {
        val objectA = ClassA()

        // globalObject is implicitly passed to doSomething here
        objectA.doSomething()
    }
    println(globalObject.list)
}

class ClassA {
    context(SomeGlobalObject)
    fun doSomething() {
        val resultA = "A..."
        // 'this@SomeGlobalObject' is redundant here, but just to be clear
        this@SomeGlobalObject.add(resultA)
        val objectB = ClassB()

        // globalObject is implicitly passed to doSomething here
        objectB.doSomethingElse()
    }
}

class ClassB {
    context(SomeGlobalObject)
    fun doSomethingElse() {
        val resultB = "B..."

        // 'this@SomeGlobalObject' is redundant here, but just to be clear
        this@SomeGlobalObject.add(resultB)
    }
}

class SomeGlobalObject {
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>()

    fun add(x: Any) {
        println("Adding $x...")
        list.add(x)
    }
}

You can also make a function require multiple context receivers of different types. See the KEEP proposal for more features.

I don’t think this solves the second half of the OP problem description. They don’t want to have to pass references down to classes, so they probably also don’t want to have to pass it down to all their function calls, and some of these functions may not even be called externally (public).

Their second code block shows how they do not want to manually pass references to the global object down into functions within ClassA. Having to use with to call that function means you still had to pass the reference down to make it a parameter of with.

@Tenfour04 Yeah of course you need to call with. How else would you provide the context object? That's how you provide the context, and generally you do this once. Everywhere else that needs the context is just marked context(MyGlobalObject). Ideally there is just one with call for each context you want to pass. Each context instance will then be passed between the functions all implicitly. with is kind of the "root" of the call tree.

@Tenfour04 context(SomeGlobalObject) to with is like suspend to runBlocking. You get what I mean? suspend is also a kind of "context", and runBlocking is how you "enter" this context from non-suspend code.

The way I interpret the OP’s question, there is no possible solution in Kotlin, precisely because they do not want to have to pass the context except maybe one time when ClassA is instantiated. Then ClassA and some other classes that ClassA uses can use that context reference implicitly without ever mentioning it.
